# Modifying values inside tuples

Tags: swift, tuples

I have an array of tuples like so:

```
var tupleArray = [(userPhoto:UIImage?, student:PSStudent?, staff:PSStaff?)] = []
```

After adding values to that array, I would like to iterate through it and modify the `userPhoto` value for each tuple as I go. Here is how I'm iterating:

```
for tuple in tupleArray {
    let newImage = UIImage(systemName:"test")
    tuple.userPhoto = newImage
}
```

However, when I try to set the value for `userPhoto` inside the tuple, I'm shown the following:

> Cannot assign to value: 'tuple' is a 'let' constant.

I'm sure there's some basic misunderstanding I have about variable tuples. Is what I'm attempting possible, or do I need to recreate the entire tupleArray inside a new variable and then assign that to the old one?

Comment: When you iterate using a `for` loop then the variable (in this case `tuple`) is always `let` declared, this is not something that is special for tuples

Comment: You could instead use an index to access the array,`for index in tupleArray.indices { tupleArray[index].userPhoto = UIImage(systemName:"test") }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index variable `tuple` is an immutable **copy** of the array item, even if it was mutable it won't modify the array.

You have to access the item in the array directly by index

```
for (index, _) in tupleArray.enumerated() {
    let newImage = UIImage(systemName:"test")
    tupleArray[index].userPhoto = newImage
}
```

or simpler and more efficient

```
let newImage = UIImage(systemName:"test")
for index in tupleArray.indices  {
    tupleArray[index].userPhoto = newImage
}
```

Side note: The issue is related to array, not to tuple. Anyway Apple recommends to prefer a custom struct over a tuple if the object is not temporary.

Comment: for third approach, indices can combine with keyPath like this: 
tupleArray.indices.forEach {
tupleArray[$0][keyPath: \. userPhoto] = newImage
}